# Xdebug for Sublime Text 3 not working on OSx 10.11 via homebrew

Tags: php, ssl, xdebug

Hoping someone can spot my problem.

Trying to run Xdebug for Sublime Text 3 for *local* development and when I set breakpoint(s) and run Xdebug > Start Debugging (Launch Browser), nothing happens - the pages load and nothing is logged

I'm running Apache 2.4 and php 7.0.20 via homebrew

I have Xdebug installed via homebrew. When running http://localhost/phpinfo.php, I see xdebug installed

Here are my settings in /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

And here are my .sublime-project settings

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "path_mapping": {
            "/Users/xxxx/Sites/xxxx/web" : "/Users/xxxx/Sites/xxxx/web"
        },
        "url": "https://local-project.com/"
    }
}
}
```

Other than trying different port numbers, anyone have a suggestion?

I'm using local ssl via openssl on port 443 - I guess I could change to http on port 80 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried running the local website via http on port 80 with no dice, so it looks like something beyond an ssl issue.

Comment: 1) Not a Mac or Sublime user .. but if your xdebug uses `9001` port (from php.ini) then where you do specify it in Sublime? if it's not specified then it may still be listening on standard `9000`... 2) Enable xdebug logging and see where it tries to connect (and whet the response is) -- if it tries to connect at all, of course.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne I don't think SublimeText needs the port information as I think it's just displaying the logging but you're right, looking to the logging directly will show whether it's an issue with SublimeText or my Xdebug setup